# External Module causes os.path.isfile to return incorrect answer

Tags: python

I am running Python 2.7 under Windows7 on an iMAC (using BOOTCAMP) and have encountered a strange problem or bug. Here is my problem script boiled down to essentials:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping as mapping
import os

for fileName in os.listdir("TestDir"):
    fullPath = os.path.join("TestDir", fileName)
    #hexpath=':'.join(x.encode('hex') for x in fullPath)
    #print hexpath
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        print fullPath + " is a file"
        desc = arcpy.Describe(fullPath)
        if(desc.datatype == "MapDocument"):
            #mxd = mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
            #del mxd
            print "MAP FILE: " + fileName
    else:
        print fullPath + " is not a file"
```

When the line "mxd=" is commented I get the correct output

```
TestDir\A_layer.lyr is a file
TestDir\Mapfile1.mxd is a file
MAP FILE: Mapfile1.mxd
TestDir\Z_file is a file
```

When the line is uncommented I get:

```
TestDir\A_layer.lyr is a file
TestDir\Mapfile1.mxd is a file
MAP FILE: Mapfile1.mxd
TestDir\Z_file is not a file
```

The last line printed differs and is WRONG. (I get the correct behavior again if I uncomment the "del mxd" line).

Without getting into details about what the external module does,
or simply dismissing the module as buggy, my question is:

**What possible bug or type of bug in the mapping.MapDocument method could possibly lead to such a behavior? How can a bug in a user written module affect so profoundly the output of a built-in library?**

Unfortunately the source of the arcpy module is not available to me. It is vendor proprietary. The vendor asserts that in their testing the bug cannot be reproduced with very similar test case on the same platform and Python version.

Comment: What does `mapping.MapDocument` do? Does it create temporary files in that `TestDir` that might overwrite a regular file with something different? Or just delete it? Or could it be `chdir`-ing? (You can test the first by looking at the creation/mod/access times on the file, with `dir` from outside the script or `os.stat` from inside, before and after; you can test the second by printing `os.getcwd()` before and after.)

Comment: Also, can you add `os.stat(fullPath)` and show what it looks like in the two different cases?

Comment: Abarnert you are the man! Yes, the stupid call has changed the current working directory. So I presume it means that the "del" statement undoes that. Not something I would have expected.

Comment: Well, `chdir` may seem improbable and stupid, but compared to, say, monkey-patching `os.path`, it seemed like a better guess as to how it might be screwing you up. (It could be worse; I once had to deal with an .iso library that would `chdir` into a temporary directory, delete it, and leave me there if anything failed…)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is apparently that the `mapping.MapDocument` constructor changes the current working directory. This means that you're not looking for `TestDir\Z_File` under the original working directory, you're looking for it under a different directory, and there is no such file, and `isfile` returns False for no such file, not just for being a directory or other non-file thing.

The best workaround is probably to [`abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) all of your paths before ever constructing a `MapDocument`.